# Consumable item could only be consumed once in Unity In-App Purchase

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, unity-game-engine

I am 100% sure I am registering my item as ProductType.Consumable in Unity 5.3. However, I could not pay for the item the second time via Google Play payment system. What have I missed out?

Comment: You need to call a FinishTransaction method to consume the consumable. So that Google knows the user did get his reward.

Comment: That seemed to solve my problem. You should have posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call a [FinishTransaction](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Purchasing.Extension.AbstractStore.FinishTransaction.html) method to [consume](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityIAPProcessingPurchases.html) the [consumable](https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/purchase-iab-products.html#Consume). So that Google knows the user did get his reward.